# Apply Control Template in XAML

Tags: wpf, silverlight

This should be really simple.  How do I apply a ControlTemplate to a Thumb in XAML?

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="temp">
        <Ellipse Width="60" Height="30" Fill="Black"/>
    </ControlTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
    <TextBlock>Not Dragged</TextBlock>
    <Canvas x:Name="foo">
        <Thumb Width="150" Height="50" DragDelta="Thumb_DragDelta" x:Name="simpleDrag">

        </Thumb>
        <TextBlock>Dragged (hopefull)</TextBlock>
    </Canvas>
</Grid>
```

I can't figure out how to apply the "temp" template to the Thumb.  Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You'd use the [`Template`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.template.aspx) property:

```
<Thumb Width="150" ... Template="{StaticResource temp}" />
```